# Hide and show again div

Tags: javascript, click, hide, show

How do I need to change my code if I click `.menu` again, I want to show `.work`?

```
$(".menu").click(function () {
    $(".work").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Change `none` to `block` or any other possible value for `display` that causes the element to get visible again.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery's `.toggle` method:

https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$(".menu").click(function () {
    $(".work").toggle();
});
```